# Android constraint layout button floating to top

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Im having some weird issues with the constraint layout on Android:

[image]

As you can see in the above image, the next button is positioned in the lower right of the screen (it's constrained to the right and bottom of the parent)

However when I run the application on my phone this is the result:
[image]

For some reason the button floats to the top of the screen.

Heres the entire layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        style="@style/headerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Enter Your Name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="blah blah blah"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="Next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening?

Thanks

**Edit** Added inflation code

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_name, container, false);
    }
```

Comment: check your constraint layout dependency are latest or not

Comment: How do you inflate your layout? Maybe the ConstraintLayout does not fill the entire screen for some reason.

Comment: I have checked your code it's running fine on my side.

Comment: its working fine from my side, you can clear and rebuild app if it's not worked.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your project or run it on a physical device, if you are running it on an emulator.

Comment: I've done a clean and rebuild with no difference. The second screenshot was taken on my Google pixel so it's not an emulator issue. I'm inflating the view in a fragment in the usual way

Comment: Looks like your ConstraintLayout parent have layout_height="wrap_content". Could you show how you inflate it?

Comment: Check the layout inspector to see the true size of the _ConstraintLayout_. Tools->Layout Inspector then select your app. Looks like the parent of the _ConstraintLayout_ is constraining its size. The layout inspector will shed some light.

Comment: Looks like the `ConstraintLayout` has a height of `match_parent`... so the logical question is what is the parent? Are you adding a fragment to a `FrameLayout` in your Activity? What is the height of that FrameLayout?

Comment: I suspect that your fragment is being hosted inside a view that has `wrap_content` set for its height.

Answer (score 0):

@Cheticamp Thats a really cool trick, I didn't know about that one. And that has shown the problem which appears to be as a few people have pointed out, my fragment was being inflated into an activity with a height of wrap_content so it was being squashed. Its all working now. Thankyou everyone for taking the time the help, this feels like a fairly easy problem to fall into while you're still learning how fragments and activities are used together

Comment: Glad it helped. Layout inspector is one of those "open" secrets that everyone should make use of.